# Broken packages 22.04

Tags: apt, dpkg, kde

I installed Ubuntu successfully and am now trying to install KDE, but I am getting errors.

During installation I get the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
muon : Depends: software-properties-qt but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried several commands such as:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt--fix-missing update
sudo apt install -f
apt autoremove
apt dist-upgrade
apt --fix broken install
```

It shows all packages are up to date, or 0 new files found, 0 upgrade, 0 deleted, or 0 packages needing to be fixed

Then I try and use `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

That command doesn't do anything, as it just give me new blank line

[After entering dpkg --configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGeUw.png)

Ivye tried to find the file in question but I can't find it.

I could make it easier and just install Kubuntu, but I already have personal files and accounts linked.

[device im using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljEFf.png)

I'm new to using Ubuntu and Linux.

Comment: Please include the full output that came before "some packages could not be installed" including the exact commands you typed in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) - if you insist on fixing this installation, start here.  If you need more help, please include all commands you are using and the entire output of each command. Please format appropriately using code fences (see my edit for examples) -- *Do Not* upload pictures of text and *do not* manipulate inside the pasted output. Add code fences before and after the whole paste. Don't change anything inside the paste

Comment: You gave no clues as to how you installed KDE, if you used the default Ubuntu repository version of made changes to your sources before you tried installing packages (*which is key*), as I've added KDE a couple of times to an existing Ubuntu 22.04 system without issue so it's likely something you did before the commands you provided that created an issue, but we have no command output thus can't help you with messages as we cannot read them.